# Stray Capacitance in my load waveform?

Tags: inductor, oscilloscope, capacitance, waveform

I have just taken this trace of my Loadwave form for  PWM controlled halogen dimmer.

I was wondering if anyone could identify the cause of the transients below or above zero volts for each polarity. 
That is, why does the waveform seem to dip below zero (or above) when switching.

This was taken with my USB oscilloscope and the PWM frequency is 31.25kHz

The circuit composed of two mosfets who PWM the power to a halogen bulb from a toroidal transformer.

The leads to the bulb are quite long.

Any indication as to what is causing this would be of great help!
[image: My Circuit]
[image: LoadWaveform Of my Halogen Dimmer]

Comment: We have no schematics and no information where exactly this trace was measured. We can make assumptions, but would that be a good idea?

Comment: Updated with schematic. 
This trace was taken across the load resistance (bublb)

Comment: How did you precisely connect the oscilloscope.

Comment: The oscillioscope probes were connected to the drain of the upper FET and to the opposite side of the load resistance. 

The probe was in X10 Mode as my USB scope maxed out at X1 and seemed to clip the output.

Answer (score 2):

My first guess would be inductive pick-up in your scope probe.

Try to make the GND loop connection from your scope probe to your board smaller in area (it's all about area for inductive pick-up) - keep it as close as possible to the side of the scope probe. Also try tightly twisting the leads to the bulb if they are, as you said, quite long.

Hopefully what you are seeing are measurement artefacts and, if so, should be reduced with the techniques described.

Comment: the ground clip of my probe is going to the ground track of my breadboard, so the surface area of this ground connection is indeed larger than it need be. 

Is it possible that this is causing the issue?

Comment: That sounds like it could be the issue. Connect the ground clip of the probe as near as you can to the point you are measuring.